# MISRA C++ Rule 5-0-4

Tags: c++, misra

```
for(uint32_t j=0;<unwrapped_merge_data_cnt;j++)
```

I have no idea to solve it.
Error message:

> implicit conversion from signed char to uint32_t.

Comment: Please copy-paste code and error messages directly into the question. Transcribing can lead to errors, e.g. the code appears to be missing a `j` in the conditional, and the error message probably said "conversion" instead of "conversation".

Comment: Is the condition `j < unwrapped_merge_data_cnt` instead of the posted `<unwrapped_merge_data_cnt`? What is `unwrapped_merge_data_cnt`?